# toString() changes ":" to "=" in a java hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap, tostring

I have the following

```
public static void main(String []args) throws JSONException{
        Map<String,String> varMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        varMap.put("VAR","123");
        varMap.put("OTHER_VAR","234");




        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("Variable",varMap); 
        System.out.println("JSON " + json);

    }
```

This gives me the correct result as follows

```
   JSON {"Variable":{"VAR":"123","OTHER_VAR":"234"}}
```

But in my json I can only use a String value, so changing it to following gives me an unexpected result

```
  public static void main(String []args) throws JSONException{
            Map<String,String> varMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            varMap.put("VAR","123");
            varMap.put("OTHER_VAR","234");




            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("Variable",varMap.toString()); 
            System.out.println("JSON " + json);

        }
```

Unexpected Result

```
JSON {"Variable":"{VAR=123, OTHER_VAR=234}"}
```

I can achive this by manually replacing the equal to with ":"

```
public class json{

    public static void main(String []args) throws JSONException{
        Map<String,String> varMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        varMap.put("VAR","123");
        varMap.put("OTHER_VAR","234");




        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        String jsonVarMap = varMap.toString().replace("=", ":");
        json.put("Variable", jsonVarMap); 
        System.out.println("JSON " + json);

    }
}
```

But is there a better way?
How do I change the map to an exact String?

Comment: `json.put("Variable", new JSONObject(varMap).toString());`?

Comment: Do not ever rely on the behavior of the toString method... There are proper methods of serializing to JSON...

Comment: Returns this  JSON {"Variable":"{\"VAR\":\"123\",\"OTHER_VAR\":\"234\"}"}

Comment: Try https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: also from the documentation of `AbstractMap#toString`: `Each key-value mapping is rendered as the key followed by an equals sign ("=") followed by the associated value.`. Since you just call `Map.toString`, the above described result will be delivered.

Comment: @user_mda: Yes, that's what I would expect. What do you expect?

Comment: @Ryan, I have the expected output in the question

Comment: Mmm... not as far as I can see.

Comment: @Ryan: JSON {"Variable":{"VAR":"123","OTHER_VAR":"234"}}
This is copy pasted from my question. With your solution it ntroduces a problem of getting rid of the backslashes which seems fairly complicated. Can you provide an answer with the backslashes removd? using replace isnt helping

Comment: But you said that output *wasn't* what you wanted because it had to be a string, not an object. What format do you want the string to be in? If it's a JSON string, the quotes are going to have to be escaped.

Comment: hmm it is a JSON string I need the quotes in the string, how do I do that

Answer (score 3):

This is because you use `HashMap::toString()`:

```
json.put("Variable",varMap.toString());
```

And this is the usual behaviour.

---

Replace is not bad in simple cases, but if some of your data contents a `=` it will break your json.

If you want to get correct result in a more polite mode, `extend` `HashMap` and override `toString`:

**JSonMap.java**

```
public class JSonMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String SEPARATOR = "";
    private static final char QUOTE = '"';
    private static final char DOTS = ':';    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : this.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(SEPARATOR);

            // same as sb.append("" + QUOTE + entry.getKey() + QUOTE + ":"  + QUOTE + entry.getValue() + QUOTE);
            sb.append(QUOTE);
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(QUOTE);
            sb.append(DOTS);
            sb.append(QUOTE);
            sb.append(entry.getValue());
            sb.append(QUOTE);
            SEPARATOR = ", ";
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**Execute it:**

```
Map<String,String> varMap = new JSonMap<String,String>();
varMap.put("VAR","123");
varMap.put("OTHER_VAR","234");

System.out.println(varMap);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"VAR":"123", "OTHER_VAR":"234"
```

Now, apply to your JSON to get expected result `;)`

Comment: i´m just going to add on this answer, that if you are using `java 8` the [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) could be a smooth alternative to the "append seperator" solution from this answer. Otherwise this answer is pretty complete :).

Comment: @Jordi, thank you, I was looking for something as organized as this!

Comment: @Kevin, I am on Java 7, but thansk for the info!

Comment: Although I need the quotes in the output which seem to have gone

Comment: @user_mda my mistake, please check updated tostring method scaping quotes

Comment: hmm taht gives {"Variable":"\"VAR\" : \"123\", \"OTHER_VAR\" : \"234\""}

Comment: Anyayto remove the backslashes?

Comment: No, I string manipulated after converting it to a json String. But tahnsk for your help